# Intercept calls to DOM API functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, jsdom, es6-proxy

I need to intercept calls to some DOM API functions and store their arguments as a side effect. For example, suppose that I'm interested in the functions `getElementsByTagName`and `getElementById`. See example below:

```
"use strict";
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
let document = jsdom.jsdom("<html><head></head><body><div id='foo'><div></div></div></body></html>");
let cpool = {ids: [], tags: []};
let obj = document.getElementById("foo");
// --> cpool = {ids: ["foo"], tags: []}
obj.getElementsByTagName("div"); 
// --> cpool = {ids: ["foo"], tags: ["div"]}
```

One **important note** is that I'm using *node.js* and `document` object is implemented by the *jsdom* library. So far I tried to exploit ES6 Proxies to modify the behaviour of the aforementioned DOM functions.

That is how I tried to proxify *document* object to trap all method calls. I wonder if and how using this technique or some other one I can get the solution to my problem.

```
let documentProxy = new Proxy(document, {
    get(target, propKey, receiver) {
        return function (...args) {
            Reflect.apply(target, propKey, args);
            console.log(propKey + JSON.stringify(args));
            return result;
        };
    }
});    
documentProxy.getElementById("foo");
// --> getElementById["foo"]
```

Comment: I don't know why, but it sounds like you're doing a bad thing...

Comment: @evolutionxbox what do you mean by `bad thing`?

Comment: What is your [actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) that you try to solve by intercepting these calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to intercept only calls to these two functions, you don't need to use Proxy. You can just store a copy of the original function, and override the function to which you want intercept calls with a function that saves the arguments and then calls the original function.

```js
const cpool = {ids: [], tags: []}

;(getElementsByTagNameCopy => {
  document.getElementsByTagName = tag => {
    cpool.tags.push(tag)
    return Reflect.apply(getElementsByTagNameCopy, document, [tag])
  }
})(document.getElementsByTagName)

;(getElementsByTagNameCopy => {
  Element.prototype.getElementsByTagName = function(tag) {
    cpool.tags.push(tag)
    return Reflect.apply(getElementsByTagNameCopy, this, [tag])
  }
})(Element.prototype.getElementsByTagName)

;(getElementByIdCopy => {
  document.getElementById = id => {
    cpool.ids.push(id)
    return Reflect.apply(getElementByIdCopy, document, [id])
  }
})(document.getElementById)

console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('body'))
console.log(document.getElementById('whatever'))
console.log(document.body.getElementsByTagName('div'))
console.log(cpool)
```

Comment: It only tracks calls on the document object, not on the _Element_. For example here `console.log(document.getElementById('test').getElementsByTagName('span'));` _span_ is not stored among tags.

Comment: doesn't seem practical to overwrite each individual method; just saying.

Comment: @Gothdo Your solution gives the right answer. Thanks for the idea! The only problem still left is to achieve the same effect using in _node.js_ with _jsdom_.

Comment: @AlexElyasov It should work fine in Node.js with jsdom, you only need to replace `Element` with `document.defaultView.Element`.

Comment: though it still feels that _Proxies_ is something that could make the solution less boilerplate.

Comment: @Gothdo Do you know if that could be extended to object properties? I experimented with`document.defaultView.Element.prototype.className`, but couldn't make it work...